# Issue with css first-of-type

Tags: css, html

I'm having and issue with the first-of-type selector not being recognized. I'm laying out a grid of images, and I'd like the first image (a 'block' class or 'tallblock' class) to not have any padding on the left, and for the last image in the row to not have padding on the right. To achieve this, I'm using the first-of-type and last-of-type selectors. It works great for all the rows, except for the rows that have a 'tallblock' element.

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="row pure-g">
    <div class="tallblock pure-u-1-3">
        {{content}}
    </div>

    <div class="block pure-u-2-3">
        {{content}}
    </div>

    <div class="block pure-u-1-3">
        {{content}}
    </div>

    <div class="block pure-u-1-3">
        {{content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following css:

```
block{
    padding: 0px 4px;

    img{
        max-height: 310px;
    }

    &:first-of-type{
        padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
    }

    &:last-of-type{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
    }
}

.tallblock{
    padding: 0rem 4px;

    img{
    max-height: 628px;
    }

    &:first-of-type{
        padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
    }

    &:last-of-type{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
    }
}
```

For some reason, the first 'block' element (after 'tallblock') is not being selected by the first-of-type selector. Halp?

Comment: You can't use `first`. `last` or `nth` on **classes** only elements.

Comment: Try `:first-child` and `:last-child` instead of `:first-of-type` etc. Also, you can use `first` and `last` on classes. http://jsfiddle.net/TGSP6/

Comment: CSS3 `nth-*`, `first-of-type` or `last-of-type` selectors, look for the **element** itself within their parent. not the combination of `element.class` or the `.class`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense then, so I'll have to wrap them in another dom element.

Comment: The code isn’t CSS, and it is not clear what exactly you wish to accomplish. It seems that you think of `first-of-type` as `first-of-class` (which does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `:first-child` and `:last-child` instead:

```
.tallblock{
    padding: 0rem 4px;

    img{
    max-height: 628px;
    }

    &:first-child{
        padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
    }

    &:last-child{
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
    }
}
```